# Differentiate between generic algorithm & traditional algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want difference points between generic algorithm and traditional algorithm .
please need some points.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little research, i've found a lot of articles. One of the key points is that:

> A standard genetic algorithm deals with a set (a population) of
>   possible solutions (individuals) of a problem.  Each individual is a
>   point in the search space, so we can think of the genetic algorithm as
>   a multi-point optimization technique for multi-dimensional spaces. 
>   Usually, the size of the population is in the range from 20 to 200 or
>   300.  The majority of traditional optimization methods explores 1, 2, or 3 points in the search space on each iteration.
>
> Traditional methods require a starting point to begin the
>   optimization.  Often the quality of the final solution is very
>   dependent upon the position of this starting point in the search
>   space.  The choice of a starting point plays a significant role in
>   finding a good solution to the problem with a large number of local
>   optima.  Genetic algorithms, which offer many solutions and can search
>   multiple points simultaneously, do not suffer as much from this
>   drawback.

And also:

> Genetic algorithms use probabilistic transition rules, not
>   deterministic rules

I suggest you to do some research, i've found plenty of articles.

You can start with [this article.](https://es.scribd.com/document/56047069/Genetic-Algorithms-Versus-Traditional-Methods)